# MS SQL 2005 - Backup "being used by another process"

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server-2005, sql

I'm trying to create a backup file of a database in SQL 2005.  When I try to execute the backup operation I get an error saying "cannot access this file, it is in use by another process".  Any advice on what I have to do to get this working?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post actual error codes and messages; what happens when you run
`BACKUP DATABASE [yourdatabase] TO DISK='C:\temporarybackup.bak' WITH COPY_ONLY` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this database wasn't being used anymore and I ended up reformatting.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to put the database in single-user mode?  Try to back it up that way as a test.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you have another program running against that database, for example Visual Studio, or have log file open in notepad or something?

Comment: I don't believe so.  I have a ColdFusion app that reads from the database - nothing that writes to it.

Comment: I know I've seen this, just can't remember exactly what I did to resolve it...did you check to ensure that you're backing up to a file backup device, and not to the database itself?  I think that's how it happened to me, I hadn't added a file device and properly set it as destination for the backup.